# How to assign the largest n bit unsigned integer to a BigInteger in Java

Tags: java, biginteger

I have a scenario where I'm working with large integers (e.g. 160 bit), and am trying to create the biggest possible unsigned integer that can be represented with an `n` bit number at run time.  The exact value of n isn't known until the program has begun executing and read the value from a configuration file.  So for example, `n` might be 160, or 128, or 192, etcetera...

Initially what I was thinking was something like:

```
BigInteger.valueOf((long)Math.pow(2, n));
```

but then I realized, the conversion to long that takes place sort of defeats the purpose, given that long is not comprised of enough bits in the first place to store the result.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### On the largest n-bit unsigned number

Let's first take a look at what this number is, mathematically.

In an unsigned binary representation, the largest *n*-bit number would have all bits set to 1. Let's take a look at some examples:

> `1`<sub>(2)</sub>`= 1 =`2<sup>1</sup> - 1
>   `11`<sub>(2)</sub>`= 3 =`2<sup>2</sup> - 1
>   `111`<sub>(2)</sub>`= 7 =`2<sup>3</sup> - 1
>   `:`
>   `1………1`<sub>(2)</sub>`=`2<sup>*n*</sup> -1
>      <sup>*n*</sup>

Note that this is analogous in decimal too. The largest 3 digit number is:

> `10`<sup>3</sup>`- 1 = 1000 - 1 = 999`

Thus, a subproblem of finding the largest *n*-bit unsigned number is computing 2<sup>n</sup>.

---

#### On computing powers of 2

Modern digital computers can compute powers of two efficiently, due to the following pattern:

> 2<sup>0</sup>`= 1`<sub>(2)</sub>
>   2<sup>1</sup>`= 10`<sub>(2)</sub>
>   2<sup>2</sup>`= 100`<sub>(2)</sub>
>   2<sup>3</sup>`= 1000`<sub>(2)</sub>
>   `:`
>   2<sup>*n*</sup>`= 10………0`<sub>(2)</sub>
>          <sup>*n*</sup>

That is, 2<sup>*n*</sup> is simply a number having its bit *n* set to 1, and everything else set to 0 (remember that bits are numbered with zero-based indexing).

---

#### Solution

Putting the above together, we get this simple solution using [`BigInteger`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for our problem:

```
final int N = 5;
BigInteger twoToN   = BigInteger.ZERO.setBit(N);
BigInteger maxNbits = twoToN.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);

System.out.println(maxNbits); // 31
```

If we were using `long` instead, then we can write something like this:

```
// for 64-bit signed long version, N < 64
System.out.println(
    (1L << N) - 1
); // 31
```

There is no "set bit *n*" operation defined for `long`, so traditionally bit shifting is used instead. In fact, a `BigInteger` analog of this shifting technique is also possible:

```
System.out.println(
    BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(N).subtract(BigInteger.ONE)
); // 31
```

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Binary numeral system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system)
- [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)

---

#### Additional `BigInteger` tips

`BigInteger` does have a [`pow`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow%28int%29) method to compute non-negative power of any arbitrary number. If you're working in a modular ring, there are also [`modPow`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger%29) and [`modInverse`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modInverse%28java.math.BigInteger%29).

You can individually [`setBit`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#setBit%28int%29), [`flipBit`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#flipBit%28int%29) or just [`testBit`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#testBit%28int%29). You can get the overall [`bitCount`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitCount%28%29), perform bitwise [`and`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#and%28java.math.BigInteger%29) with another `BigInteger`, and [`shiftLeft`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#shiftLeft%28int%29)/[`shiftRight`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#shiftRight%28int%29), etc.

As bonus, you can also compute the [`gcd`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#gcd%28java.math.BigInteger%29) or check if the number [`isProbablePrime`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime%28int%29).

*ALWAYS* remember that `BigInteger`, like `String`, is *immutable*. You can't invoke a method on an instance, and expect that instance to be modified. Instead, always assign the *result* returned by the method to your variables.

Comment: Great answer.  The part about using setBit to set the bit at position n where everything has a ZERO based index clarified this for me. I'd been thinking about setBit as setting the nth bit, where as with the zero based indexing, it's really the n+1th bit (at index n) in a line of bits getting set.

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify you want the *largest* n bit number (ie, the one will all n-bits set).  If so, the following will do that for you:

```
BigInteger largestNBitInteger = BigInteger.ZERO.setBit(n).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
```

Which is mathematically equivalent to 2^n - 1.  Your question has how you do 2^n which is actually the smallest n+1 bit number.  You can of course do that with:

```
BigInteger smallestNPlusOneBitInteger = BigInteger.ZERO.setBit(n);
```

Comment: Wouldn't using setBit(n) on BigInteger.ZERO only set one (the high order or low order I'm not sure) bit out of n bits? e.g. for a 160 bit number you'd have one bit set to 1 and 159 bits still set to 0, resulting in a number much smaller than the largest n bit number?  Or is my interpretation of how setBit works wrong?

Comment: @Stephen - does setBit set the high or low order bit?  If it's low order bit, subtracting one would give you the integer 0 wouldn't it (bits 00000...0)?  And if it was high order bit, subtracting one would take you from a number like 10000...0 to 01111...1, which is still only approximately half the largest number 11111....1?

Comment: @Bryce - you can read the javadoc for yourself here - http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#setBit(int)

Comment: Right I think I understand it now.  When I read the javadoc initially I was ignoring the shift and logical OR operator description, which turns out to be more useful than the sentence description.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is **pow** method directly in BigInteger. You can use it for your purpose

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked the pow method.  So for reference I'm now using BigInteger.valueOf(2L).pow(n).subtract(BigInteger.ONE), which is effectively 2^n - 1, which as pointed out by Dean is the largest number that can be represented with n bits.

Comment: Good to hear that it works... :). I never tried it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way I can think of doing this is by using the constructor for `BigInteger` that takes a `byte[]`.

`BigInteger(byte[] val)` constructs the `BigInteger` Object from an array of bytes. You are, however, dealing with bits, and so creating a byte[] that might consist of {127, 255, 255, 255, 255} for  a 39 bit integer representing 2^40 - 1 might be a little tedious.

You could also use the constructor `BigInteger(String val, int radix)` - which might be readily more apparently what's going on in your code if you don't mind a performance hit for parsing a String. Then you could generate a string like `val = "111111111111111111111111111111111111111"` and then call `BigInteger myInt = new BigInteger(val, 2);` - resulting in the same 39 bit integer.

The first option will require some thinking about how to represent your number. That particular constructor expects a two's-compliment, big-endian representation of the number. The second will likely be marginally slower, but much clearer.

EDIT: Corrected numbers. I thought you meant represent 2^n, and didn't correctly read the largest value n bits could store.